# Select UITabbarItem from embedded Container UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, segue

How can I select programmatically a `UITabbarController` item from a `UISegment` from other `ViewController`?

`ViewcontrollerA` has a `UISegmentControl` and a `ContainerView`

`UITabbarControllerB` is embedded in the `ContainerView` from `ViewControllerA` and has itself two `ViewControllers` `VCItemA` and `VCItemB`.

Now the problem is, I can't change the `VCItem` from `UITabbarControllerB` via the `SegmentControl` from `UIViewcontrollerA`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try inside `ViewcontrollerA`  ( Swift)

```
if let tab = self.children.first as? UITabbarControllerB {
   tab.selectedIndex = // 0 or 1
}
```

---

( Objective - C )

```
if ([self.childViewController.firstObject isKindOfClass:UITabbarControllerB.self])
  UITabbarControllerB* tab = (UITabbarControllerB*) self.childViewController.firstObject;
  tab.selectedIndex = // 0 or 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have a example for objective-c ?

Comment: assigned that class `UITabbarControllerB` in in IB for the tab ?? if not then replace in answer every `UITabbarControllerB` with `UITabbarController`